# Вывод интерпретатора Ruby

Tags: python, qt

скажите пожалуйста, каким образом я могу перехватить вывод интерпретатора Ruby средствами Python или Qt? Т.е. сообщения об ошибках и все такое, чтобы вывести это в стандартный QTextEdit? Пробовал через subprocess и QProcess, но не получилось.

Частично получилось сделать следующим образом:

```
    self.process = QProcess()
    self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.read_data)
def run(self):
    self.process.start("C:\Ruby26-x64\\bin\\ruby.exe E:\\1.rb")
def read_data(self):
    s = self.process.readAllStandardError()
    self.text_edit.setText(str(s))
```

где run привязана к кнопке. Но так она ловит не все ошибки (во всяком случае, мне так показалось), если сравнивать с RubyMine.

Как вариант можно присоединиться к процессу и читать с него, но как это делать я не знаю.

Пробовал еще вариант

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['cmd.exe', 'irb'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.read(1)
print(proc.stdout)
```

Выдает в консоль PyCharm знаки вопроса (видимо что-то с кодировкой).

Нагуглил еще такой способ

```
a = 'ruby E:\\irb.rb'
b = os.popen(a,'r',1)
for line in b:
    print(line)
```

после чего консоль PyCharm переходит в inspect mode и имитирует irb, правда приложение при этом виснет. По хорошему, хотелось бы, вообще, читать весь оутпут консоли.

Comment: Все, вроде разобрался, чуть позже отпишусь.

Answer (score 1):

Функция компиляции скриптов:

```
def run_script(self):
    f = open('E:/Ruby21/bin/test.rb', 'w')
    f.write(self.text_edit_1.toPlainText())
    f.close()

    MyOut = Popen(['ruby', 'E:/Ruby21/bin/test.rb\n'], stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT)
                           
    stdout, stderr = MyOut.communicate()

    self.text_edit_2.setText(stdout.decode())
```

Функция irb пока не доделана, но уже ясно, как ее реализовать, вот функция, привязанная к некоторой кнопке и посылающая irb выражение 1+1 (естественно, послать можно, что угодно):

```
    self.process = QProcess()
    self.process.start('E:/ruby22-x64/bin/irb.bat')
    self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.read_data)
def irb(self):
    self.process.write(b"1+1\n")
def read_data(self):
    s = self.process.readAllStandardOutput()
    self.text_edit_3.setText(str(s))
```

Comment: Хорошая работа! А с файлом советую работать так: `with open('E:/Ruby21/bin/test.rb', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:` `f.write(self.text_edit_1.toPlainText())`, кодировку лучше всегда указывать, чтобы не было там системной, а оператор `with` сам закроет файл